# how can we define the index of array in foreach loop for adding/dividng two different array values

Tags: php

hi everyone i fetch the array by using foreach loop now how can i define the index of different elements in array for futher computation like i want the element1 of array 1 to be divided by element1 of array 2 
code of for each loop

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $data_t1 = $_POST['t1'];

    foreach ($data_t1 as $key => $value) {

        echo 'T1: ' . $value . '<br />';
        echo 'T2: ' . $_POST['t2'][$key] . '<br />';
          echo 'T3: ' . $_POST['a1'][$key] . '<br />';
        echo 'Username: ' . $_POST['username'][$key] . '<br /><br />';

    }
      $data_t2 = $_POST['t2'];
      $data_t3=$_POST['a1'];
      $data_t4=$_POST['username'];


}
var_dump($data_t1);
var_dump($data_t2);
var_dump($data_t3);
var_dump($data_t4);
?>
```

now i want these array values to be used for further computation

```
echo "Measuring Efficiency ";
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
<tr>
<th>Inputs</th>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($data_t4 as $t4)
  {
  echo $t4;         this display the values of array 4
  }
  foreach($data_t1 as $t1)
  {
  echo $t1;
$r=round(($t1/$t4),2);  
$fr=round(($t1/$t4),2); 
$br=round(($t1/$t4),2); 

echo "<td>" ."Room Size/Consumption". "</td>";
echo "<td>".$r. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$fr. "</td>";
echo "<td>".$br. "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  }

  ?
```

how can i define the index of array for division of elements of two array

my result is

$data_t1 [12 12]    $data_t4 [1.44 4.32] $data_t2 [2 4] $data_t3 [2 3]

i want to divide 12/1.44,2/1.44 2/1.44  n   12/4.32  4/4.32 3/4.32

how can i do ths

Comment: Can you be more clear? I have no idea what you just asked :)

Comment: like array1[1 2 3 4] n array2[2 4 5 6] i want to divide 1/2 how can define the index for this

Comment: Array indices are meant to traverse and identify individual array elements. Why would you want to define an index for dividing the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$array_1 = array(10,30,50,70,90);
$array_2 = array(1,3,5,7,9);
foreach($array_1 as $i => $v){
    $array_1[$i] = $array_1[$i]/$array_2[$i];
}
print_r($array_1);

Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 10
)
```

Or do you want to do something similar with the keys, not the values like so.

```
$array_1 = array(
    10=>234234,
    30=>234,
    50=>23443,
    70=>234,
    90=>234
);
$array_2 = array(
    1=>32423,
    3=>4232,
    5=>2342,
    7=>234,
    9=>234
);


$array_a = array_keys($array_1);
$array_b = array_keys($array_2);

foreach($array_a as $i => $v){
    $tmp[$i] = $array_a[$i]/$array_a[$i];
}

print_r($tmp);


Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
)
```

OK, based on your edit I've made something new.

You said:
i want to divide
12/1.44 
2/1.44
2/1.44

12/4.32
4/4.32
3/4.32

```
$data_t4 = array(1.44,4.32);

$data_t1 = array(12,12);
$data_t2 = array(2,4);
$data_t3 = array(2,3);


$nums = array(
    't1'=>$data_t1,
    't2'=>$data_t2,
    't3'=>$data_t3,
);

$divs = $data_t4;

foreach($nums as $i => $v){
    foreach($v as $ix => $vx){
        foreach($divs as $dx => $dv){
            $data[$i]['n:'.$vx]['d:'.$dv] = $vx/$dv;
        }
    }
}


print_r($data);

Array
(
    [t1] => Array
        (
            [n:12] => Array
                (
                    [d:1.44] => 8.3333333333333
                    [d:4.32] => 2.7777777777778
                )

        )

    [t2] => Array
        (
            [n:2] => Array
                (
                    [d:1.44] => 1.3888888888889
                    [d:4.32] => 0.46296296296296
                )

            [n:4] => Array
                (
                    [d:1.44] => 2.7777777777778
                    [d:4.32] => 0.92592592592593
                )

        )

    [t3] => Array
        (
            [n:2] => Array
                (
                    [d:1.44] => 1.3888888888889
                    [d:4.32] => 0.46296296296296
                )

            [n:3] => Array
                (
                    [d:1.44] => 2.0833333333333
                    [d:4.32] => 0.69444444444444
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: sir i need to store every answer of division in seperate variable

Comment: It's stored in the array $tmp also $array_1 and $array_2 are copied to $array_a and $array_b

Comment: sir i want to perform individually every index not in the loop form $i way

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example. Show me both of the arrays with a few numbers in them. Then show me what the result will look like. Finally explain how you made the result.

Comment: sir how can i display ths result in the form of table row like                        1  8.33  2.77                                                                  2  8.33  2.77                                                                3  1.38  0.46 etc

Comment: how can i display this result by using echo statement

Comment: sir plz kindly help me in ths regards waitng for your rply